# Looking up shapes in a lists of lists

Tags: list, prolog

**Program description**

1. **Aim of the program**

My program is meant to calculate locations of shapes in a 20X15 sized plane. I have a list of shapes carrying the shape type, its id, its radius or height, and its prospective [X,Y] location on the plane. I have a different list of binary operations carrying only the shape type, its id, and its location relationship with another shape. With this information in the operations list, I should compute the [X,Y] locations of the shapes: Below is a description of the two lists:

**List of shapes**

I have a list of shapes: each shape is a list of the form:

`[[shape, id],height/radius, [X,Y]]`

A list of such shapes would look something like the below when it is printed out by Prolog:

```
[[[diamond,1],4,[_7948,_7954]],[[circle,3],6,[_7894,_7900]],[[square,1],4,[_7840,_7846]],[[circle,1],5,[_7786,_7792]]|_7800]
```

**List of operations**

A list of operations that should be carried out on the shapes each operation is of the form:

```
[[[circle,1],below,[square,1]]]
```

**This means that circle 1 should appear below square 1 on the  X,Y plane**

Such a list when printed out by prolog would look something like the following:

```
[[[circle,1],below,[square,1]]|_8016]
```

2. **The program**

So I have   `computeShapeLocations/2`. Its first argument is a list of operations and the second list is a list of shapes. It recursively goes over the list of operations getting the shape ids on both sides of the operation. eg `circle 1 - below  - sqaure 1` and sends the two shapes to the correct function to calculate the locations using CLPFD. For two shapes with a relative positioning of 'below' I use `computeShapesBelow/2` which takes two shapes each of the form `[[shape, id],height/radius, [X,Y]]`.

**Steps in ComputeShapeLocations/2:**
 1. Get an operation of the form [[[circle,1],below,[square,1]]] from the list of operations
 2. Fetch first id (circle 1), then type of relationship (below) then second id (square 1).
3. Fetch the shapes from the shapes list (ShapesOut)
4. Send the shapes to `computeShapesBelow/2`. This just uses clpfd to compare radius or height and the dimensions of my X,Y plane.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
computeShapeLocations([],_ShapesOut).
computeShapeLocations([Operation|Rest],ShapesOut) :- writeln(ShapesOut),                                                                             
                                      writeln([Operation|Rest]),                                                                             
                                      nth0(0,Operation,Subject1),                                                                            
                                      nth0(1,Operation,below),                                                                           
                                     nth0(2,Operation,Subject2),                                                                             
                                     Shape1 = [Subject1,H,Loc],                                                                          
                                     Shape2 = [Subject2,H2,Loc2],                                                                        
                                     member(Shape1,ShapesOut),
                                     member(Shape2,ShapesOut),                                                                  
                                     writeln(Shape1),                                                                            
                                     writeln(Shape2),                                                            
                                     writeln(Subject1),                                                                          
                                      writeln(Subject2),
                                     computeShapeBelow(Shape1,Shape2),                                       
                                  computeShapeLocations(Rest,ShapesOut).
computeShapeBelow(Shape1,Shape2) :- nth0(2,Shape1,Location1),                                    
                                    nth0(2,Shape2,Location2),                                                                            
                                    writeln(Shape1),                                                                             
                                    writeln(Shape2),                                                                             
                                   nth0(1,Shape1,Dim1),                                                                          
                                   nth0(1,Shape2,Dim2),                                                                          
                                   nth0(0,Location1,Xcord1),                                                                             
                                   nth0(0,Location2,Xcord2),                                                                          
                                  nth0(1,Location1,Ycord1),                                                                          
                                  nth0(1,Location2,Ycord2),                                                                       
                                  Ycord1 #> Dim1, Ycord1 #< 15-Dim1,                                                                          
                                  Xcord1 #> Dim1, Xcord1 #< 20-Dim1,                                                                          
                                  Ycord2 #> Dim2, Ycord2 #<  15-Dim2,                                                                         
                                  Xcord2 #> Dim2, Xcord2 #<  20-Dim2,                                                                         
                                  Ycord2 #> Ycord1+Dim2+Dim1.
```

**The problem:**
In `computeShapeLocations/2` my lookup is just bizarre( see step three above in steps of `computeShapeLocations/2`). I use member(ShapeId, ListOFshapesList) to fetch shapes from listofshapes given their ids [shape,id]. I then print out the results( `writeln(Shape1), writeln(Shape2)`)and the image below shows just how the behavior is wrong. For the first shape (circle,1), the result is good and `computeShapesBelow/2` even comes up with a proper limit of its X,Y location (6..14 and 6..9). For the second shape (Shape2 or square 1). It does not behave as expected and the clpfd limits result in lower infinities.

The reason is because this second search of [square,1] ignores an entry of `[[square, 1], 4, [_2166, _2172]]` which is in the list and instead somehow adds an extra  `[[square, 1], _2250, [_2262|...]]` which it then uses to mess up my results.
[image]

Comment: This argument in your base case is going to leave you with an uninstantiated anonymous variable: `[[Subject|Tail]|_]`. That's why you're seeing `_4276`, etc. What is `_` really supposed to be?

Comment: Since I am looking for shapes in a list of shapes and each shape is of the form [[circle, id], radius, [Xcordinate, Ycordinate]]  I want to match the part [circle, id]  and if that part matches, I want to get the entire shape structure ->-[[circle, id], radius, [Xcordinate, Ycordinate]]

Comment: I will try looking into it add post my findings.

Comment: I rewrote the entire question. That issue is related to instantiation if I am not wrong.

Comment: The pattern `append([], ShapesIn, ShapesOut)` can be simplified to this unification: `ShapesIn = ShapesOut`. Appending a list to an empty list yields the same list.

Comment: I've read through your question a few times. It's a bit unclear exactly what you're trying to do with your query involving `ShapesIn` and `ShapesOut`. You haven't really said what you desire the actual behavior of `shape_lookup/3` to be. Why does it have 3 arguments? If I'm looking up a shape, `S`, in a list of shapes, `Shapes`, one should only need `shape_lookup(S, Shapes)` unless you want the 3rd argument to represent something else.

Comment: I have thoroughly explained the problem and attached an output.

Comment: Prolog is punishing you for your listy internal representation and for relying on `nth0/3` in place of unification.

Comment: Hmmm how can I rewrite it?

Comment: You should send me the complete assignment, I'd like to try it myself sometime.

Comment: How do I do that? It is urgent

Comment: I'm not going to do the assignment for you. I'm just curious, because I've seen three or four pieces of it in your questions.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to try using `trace.` and then run your query. I suspect the problem is that you think you have `[circle, 1]` somewhere where you actually just have `circle` or something like that, and it's failing to match.

Comment: I will do just that. Not exactly do the assignment for me no. Probably point out exactly where I go wrong. For learning purposes.

Comment: You can find my email in my profile. I still think you would profit from using `trace` to see where the unification is failing. I'm still suspicious that there is an issue with the lists and nth0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the source of your problem is being obscured by two simple problems. I don't have all your code and I don't really know what you're trying to do, so I'll just talk about what I see and how I would proceed.

The first problem is that you are not making effective use of unification. For instance, you can replace this:

```
nth0(0,Operation,Subject1),
nth0(1,Operation,below),
nth0(2,Operation,Subject2),
```

With this:

```
[Subject1,below,Subject2] = Operation,
```

But, moreover, you don't really need `Operation` on its own, so you can move that into the head of your clause:

```
computeShapeLocations([[Subject1,below,Subject2]|Rest],ShapesOut) :-
```

As you start to make these changes your code will contract quite a bit and it should become a lot easier to see what is going on. What would make it even easier to understand would be using less listy representations. For instance, it's a little easier for me to understand what is going on in this command list:

```
[below(circle(1), square(1)), below(circle(2), square(1)), ...]
```

or even this, which you can do by adding an `:- op` declaration:

```
[circle(1) below square(1), circle(2) below square(1), ...]
```

and then your pattern matches will look even simpler, like:

```
compute(Shape1 below Shape2) :- ...
```

Similarly, for your shapes, it would be a little easier to understand what is going on if you have a little more structure:

```
shape(circle(1), 4, X@Y)
```

is a little more obvious to me than

```
[[circle,1], 4, [X,Y]]
```

I find it a little odd that you've got unbound variables inside your input list. I gather you're hoping they'll obtain values later on. I suppose there's nothing wrong with this approach, I'm just surprised to see a mixture of ground and nonground acting as inputs.

Your second source of trouble is that you're mixing several kinds of procedure together. I'm pretty sure you have a DCG parsing step going on somewhere. By parsing into this weak, listy representation in there, you're forcing yourself to do more work inside these methods destructuring your lists and obtaining their meaning. Consider:

```
command([Shape1,below,Shape2]) --> shape(Shape1), "below", shape(Shape2).
```

versus

```
command(Shape1 below Shape2) --> shape(Shape1), "below", shape(2).
```

Or,

```
shape_type(circle) --> "circle".  shape_type(square) --> "square".
shape_name(shape(Name, Size, X@Y)) --> 
    shape_type(T), integer(ID), 
    integer(Size), 
    integer(X), integer(Y), 
    { Name =.. [T, ID] }.
```

versus whatever you have now.

IOW, you could create structure during the parse that will simplify your life during the processing. Similarly, doing a lot of what looks to me like debug I/O is making your processing more complex.

```
find_shape(ShapeId, Shapes, Shape) :-
    Shape = shape(ShapeId, _, _),
    member(Shape, Shapes).

computeShapeLocations([], _).
computeShapeLocations([ShapeId1 below ShapeId2|Rest], Shapes) :-
    find_shape(ShapeId1, Shapes, Shape1),
    find_shape(ShapeId2, Shapes, Shape2),
    computeShapeBelow(Shape1, Shape2),
    computeShapeLocations(Rest, Shapes).

computeShapeBelow(shape(_, D1, X1@Y1), shape(_, D2, X2@Y2)) :-
    Y1 #> D1, Y1 #< 15 - D1,
    X1 #> D1, X1 #< 20 - D1,
    Y2 #> D2, Y2 #< 15 - D2,
    X2 #> D2, X2 #< 20 - D2,
    Y2 #> Y1 + D2 + D1.
```

I think if I were staring at this I would find it a bit easier to debug.

Comment: Sweet, I will reconfigure my code and get tell you how it goes. Thanks a bunch. Your approach is sleeker.

Comment: @/2 documentation in Swi-prolog is quite cryptic: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(@)/2.  How do you use it here?

Comment: I would declare both operators with `:- op(xfx, 700, below).` and `:- op(xfx, 400, @).` for instance. [Check the docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=op%2f3), or ignore this part of my advice.