# Checking if variables are grounded/instantiated in deterministic time

Tags: prolog

I am working with CLPFD and I want to be sure a variable holds an integer to avoid `variables not fully instantiated errors`. I therefore try to check whether variables are bound.
I have tried:

```
nonvar(Var)
ground(Var)
integer(Var)
```

They all result in running out of global stack. Is it possible to check a variable status in Prolog in deterministic time?

Comment: Something else is most likely causing the out of global stack error that you're observing. Code?

Comment: If you are getting "variables not fully instantiated" errors, then using `nonvar/1` or `ground/1` or `integer/1` is probably a poor work-around depending upon the overall code you're working with. You should show the code where you get these errors and seek another way around it.

Comment: The problem is with a list search. It searches for one element and then on the next element, it adds an alien entry of the element instead of fetching it from the list. Was thinking I could solve this by checking for variable grounding but I was wrong. The question is fully explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846556/looking-up-shapes-in-a-lists-of-lists?noredirect=1#comment90689139_51846556

Comment: *on the next element, it adds an alien entry of the element instead of fetching it from the list*. That sounds like a problem with the design of the predicate. Checking for grounding is covering that up.